# Unidentified lego bag

Tags: set-identification

This bag I can't identify. It's full of black and gray pieces. I found this bag of lego parts marked 732R3 #22. Help me know what it goes to. I've had no luck searching.

Comment: The bag markings cannot identify a set. If you add a picture, we can help. Or you can look the pieces up yourself from the linked duplicate question.